# making an VC++ .exe to DLL .is it possible?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, win32-process

I have an VC++ win 32 application which compiles into an EXE. But now I want to convert it into dll so that I can load that in  another application.I tried changing in Visual Studio properties from .EXE to .DLL which successfully converted it but whn i use GetProcAddress it always returns NULL . I am not sure what I am doing is right or wrong .

Basically this what I want to achieve :

1. I want to link project 1 and project2
2. Project 2 should be able to invoke the functions of project1(which is an exe currenlty)

**EDIT**
Hi guys thanks for your input .I told what you guys said . even then my GetProcAddress  returns zero . Am i am doing anything wrong .Shown my dll loading code  below .

```
HINSTANCE LoadMe  =  LoadLibrary( _T("D:\\VC++Project\\CVAList\\CVAList\\ExportTest.dll"));

   if (LoadMe != 0)
    printf("LoadMe library loaded!\n");
    else
     printf("LoadMe library failed to load!\n");


   EntryPointfuncPtr LibMainEntryPoint;   
   LibMainEntryPoint = (EntryPointfuncPtr)GetProcAddress(LoadMe,"PrintFloatsVal");
   LibMainEntryPoint (a1 ,a,b,c,d ); // 4 double
```

**EDIT** DLL Export Code

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport ) 


DllExport  void  PrintFloatsVal ( int amount, double &d1 ,double &d2 , double &d3 ,double &d4)
{
....
..
}
```

Comment: 1.) did you export the methods you want to call from project2? 2.) have you considered static linking which might be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the functions you wish to access using the `__declspec dllexport` keyword.

So if you add the manifest constant 'BUILDING_MY_DLL' to the project, the header file that declares the functions you care about can be used in both the DLL project and any code that uses the DLL:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_MY_DLL
#define MY_DLL_EXPORT __declspec dllexport
#else
#define MY_DLL_EXPORT __declspec dllimport
#endif
```

And decorate the functions you wish to export:

```
MY_DLL_EXPORT BOOL Func1(int a);
```

If the function you wish to access is implemented in C++ it will be decorated, for the purposes of function overloading and other purposes, and it best accessed directly like any other function.  If you wish to use `GetProcAddress()` however you are better off giving it C-linkage by surrounding the function with `extern "C" { ... }`.  This will make the exported name the same the name used within the code.

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi thanks for your input .I told what you said . even then my GetProcAddress  returns zero . Am i am anything wrong .Shown my dll loading code  below .  HINSTANCE LoadMe  =  LoadLibrary( _T("D:\\VC++Project\\CVAList\\CVAList\\ExportTest.dll"));
  
   if (LoadMe != 0)
    printf("LoadMe library loaded!\n");
 else
  printf("LoadMe library failed to load!\n");


   EntryPointfuncPtr LibMainEntryPoint;   
   LibMainEntryPoint = (EntryPointfuncPtr)GetProcAddress(LoadMe,"PrintFloatsVal");
   LibMainEntryPoint (a1 ,a,b,c,d ); // 4 double

Comment: Hey I have put the same code above(in question) with code format .

Comment: @iTion: I have editted my answer - put `extern "C" { ... }` around the function within the header file if you wish to access it using `GetProcAddress()`.